# Not sure if this LR(1) grammar has shift/reduce conflict

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, programming-languages, grammar, lr-grammar

I'm trying to solve question on LR(1) grammar :

```
S->AA 
A->Aa
A-> b
```

I got stuck in state 4 when :

```
S-> AA. ,$
A-> A.a ,$
A->.Aa ,$
A->.a ,$
```

`a` and `A` shifted to other state and `A` is reduced in the same state should I consider this grammar is not LR(1) and SLR(1) because of this conflict ?

Comment: No. The reduce is only possible with `$` as a lookahead, and there is no such thing as a shift/shift conflict, because shift is just shift.

Comment: @rici No means this gammar is LR(1)? , and is it ok to have shift and reduce in one state ?

Comment: You can have shift and reduce or multiple reduce in one state as long as you can decide which action to take using the lookahead. I didn't look carefully at the whole grammar, but this state is not a problem.

Comment: can any one provide more explanation ?

Comment: How did you get into this state? I constructed the LR1 automata for this grammar and it doesn't have such a state. @EJP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check shift-reduce(SR) or reduce-reduce(RR) problem

In state 4 which yo have mentioned there is only one reduce entry `S-> AA., $` therefore there is **no RR** problem. Check for SR :

Reduce entry for `S-> AA.,$` will be at `$` for LR(1) and at follow(S), which is `$`, for SLR(1).

**Shift entries are only checked for terminals and not variables**. Variables entry are made in **GOTO** part of the table while shift entries are made in **ACTION** part of table. Shift is only at terminal `a` in case of both SLR(1 ) and LR(1).

Therefore in state provided by you there is no problem (neither SR nor RR).